# How to determine the right dpi for a display?

Tags: xorg, display, hdpi

Whenever I run `xdpyinfo | grep dots` in the Terminal I get:

```
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

I have a 14" 2560 x 1440 screen, so I understand the dpi of this screen should be anything around 200 dpi. How does Xorg determines which is the correct dpi for the screen? I am not asking how to change the dpi configuration but how is it defined by Xorg.

Comment: Your screen has a diagonal of 2937.2 pixels. This means your ideal DPI is roughly 210.

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate. The other questions points to how to **change** the dpi settings, while my question is related to how xorg determines the dpi and if it is doing it fine.

Comment: “how xorg determines the dpi” Simple, it's hardcoded to 96 no matter what (until you set it up explicitly). It is not "fine", it is just a legacy assumption from when displays were always 96 DPI. Also Windows does a similar thing unless you change it. Setting up the right DPI value should give you a more natural UI size, and also a true "100% scale" in applications like LibreOffice or GIMP.

Comment: I can't understand how in any way this and the other questions could be the same...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Xorg might try to determine your screen size but will not always manage to do that correctly. In that case, one should set the correct screen size for that particular monitor so Xorg will know the dpi.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Display_size_and_DPI

Comment: You might want to include the essential parts of the information in your answer, as link-only answers are generally not well received here.